# How to set a folder with trailing dot permission in linux?

Tags: linux

I can see my below folders having dot at the end of permissions

```
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root   root    4096 May 26  2010 java-1.7.0
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root   root    4096 May 26  2010 java-1.6.0
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root   root    4096 May 26  2010 java-1.5.0
```

How can I create a new folder with similar permissions ?

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to do it, in case anyone needs it.... posting answer :

```
[root@XXXXX share]# chcon -h system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0 java-1.8.0
[root@XXXXXXshare]# ls -dZ java-1.8.0
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0       java-1.8.0
```

A good read: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html

Answer (score 0):

you are using a `Redhat` based distro, that means selinux permissions, you can use:

```
ls -lZ
```

From man page

```
man ls
       -Z, --context
          print any SELinux security context of each file
```

If you want to use Selinux, you can start from [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files-Persistent_Changes_semanage_fcontext.html)

Selinux permissions are a big topic.

Comment: this does not answer *How to `set` a folder with trailing dot permission in linux?*

Comment: That's ok. But, How can I set similar permission on my folder ? When I am creating a new folder it doesn't have similar dot at the end?